# Method accepts Type - How to make it accept a generic?

Tags: generics, c#-4.0, restsharp

Sorry if the title is unclear. I have a library loaded (RestSharp) and im trying to wrap a function around an API call. It looks something like this:

```
RestResponse<object> restResponse = RestClient.Execute<object>(restRequest);
```

This works. I am now trying to enclose this in a function.

```
static RestResponse<T> ApiCall<T>(object param1, object param2, ...)

RestResponse<T> restResponse = RestClient.Execute<T>(restRequest);

return restResponse;
```

The above yields "T must be a non abstract type with a public constructor to use it as a parameter of blah blah blah"

Is this a limitation of the RestClient.Execute method?

Comment: Yes. To fix it, you can constrict T

Comment: Could you please clarify?

Comment: T should be whatever generic type argument `RestClient.Execute<T>` can accept. So if it cannot accept it, your function won't work. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this can be done by:

```
static RestResponse<T> ApiCall<T>(object param1, object param2, ...) where T: new()

RestResponse<T> response = (RestResponse<T>)client.Execute<T>(request);

return restResponse;
```

I understand this can only be used if the object has a parameterless constructor.
Please feel free to chime in with some more elegant answers!